# Determine the closes point from a point $P$ to a circle which is the intersection between a sphere and plane (and $P$ and the sphere)

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, spheres

Let $M$ be the plane $2x + y + 2z = 27$, $S$ the sphere of radius $15$ centered
at the origin and let $C$ be the circle of intersection between $M$ and $S$.
Determine the points in $M$, $S$ and $C$ that lie closest to the point $P(33, 30, 6)$.
(ON-system assumed.)

(1) The closest point from $M$ to $P$ is the intersection of $L_1:P+t_1(2,1,2)$ and $M$, I got this one.

(2) The closest point from $S$ to $P$. Let $F$ be the center of the sphere. Then I think the point of intersection between the sphere and the line that goes through $P$ and $F$ is the desired point.

So $L_2:t_2 (33, 30, 6)$ and we have $S:x^2+y^2+z^2=15^2$. Then $t_2=\frac{15^2}{33^2+30^2+6^2}$, but this seems wrong.

(3) No idea.

Comment: For $t_2$ you should take the square root of your result, i.e. $$t_2={15\over \sqrt{33^2+30^2+6^2}}={5\over \sqrt{11^2+10^2+2^2}}={1\over 3}$$ Concerning c) take a closest point in $M$, the one obtained in a) and then coonect this point with the center of $C$ and find the intesection point with $C.$ So you need to determine that center of $C.$ This can be done by using the vector perpendicular to $M$ i.e. $(33,30,6)$ or $(11,10,2).$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc That's actually very interesting way of finding the closest point from P to C. It's like we are using a projection of the shortest line segment from C to P onto the plane $M$ to find the point of intersection with C.

Comment: Yes. Although I prefer to first project the point $P$ onto $M$ and then connect its projection say $P_M$ with the center of $C.$ In this way you make use of a) where you have calculated $P_M.$

Answer (score 1):

(1) Good work!

(2) This seems correct, with the exception of forgetting to take a square root.

(3) Probably possible to bash out with Lagrange multipliers, but I also believe the following geometric argument is correct. To minimize the distance from a point on $M$ to $P$, we simply need to minimize it's distance to the point calculated in part (1) (lets call this point $x_0$). Now, the problem is to find the point on both $M$ and $S$ that is closest to $x_0$. If I am not mistaken in saying that $x_0$ is outside of $C$, then it follows that this point lies between the point in $M$ closest to the origin and $x_0$. So just find the point on the line between $\frac{27}{5}(2,1,2)$ and $x_0$ with norm 15, and you are done.